# How to get selected rows including child rows of a JTree

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtree

I'm working on implementing Drag & Drop functionality on a JTree component by using a `TransferHandler`. I've used [this](https://coderanch.com/t/346509/java/JTree-drag-drop-tree-Java) old thread on CodeRanch, which is pretty much the only apparent ressource that gets linked to whenever any question regarding this comes up in any forum.

I've gotten it to work well with my Data and my UI, so that leaf-Nodes can easily be dragged and dropped. The problem comes, when I try to drag Nodes that have children. The overriden boolean function `canImport(TransferSupport support)` returns false, because it checks the selected rows on the tree. Therefore, I then tested wether I could `CTRL + Click` to manually select child nodes after selecting the "root"-node of my drag operation, which works just fine and the node, including all it's children gets drag and dropped.

My question is this: to get the selected rows, I call `tree.getSelectionRows()` and save that value to an integer array. How do I get the child-rows into that integer array? I'm aware I could probably rewrite other parts of my `TransferHandler`, but since everything else works just fine, if only it would actually select the rows how I anticipate it to, I feel like this is the simpler approach.

Comment: You should rewrite your `copy` method and create copy not only for the currently selected node, but also for all its subnodes. Please note, that this solution can provide duplicates in your `nodesToRemove` list (when user manually select subnodes of a selected node).

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy Maybe I'm understanding things wrong, but isn't that what the iteration through the `paths` object in `createTransferable()` is for? The problem there once again seems to be the call `tree.getSelectionPaths()` only returning manually selected paths, not child elements.

Comment: The issue is with the call to `haveCompleteNode`, as the comments says `// Do not allow MOVE-action drops if a non-leaf node is selected unless all of its children are also selected.`.  This seems a bit weird to me, as selecting a branch node should carry it's children with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, drag and drop is ... complicated.  There are lots of gotchas you need to be aware of.

In the linked example you should beware that it's dealing with `DefaultMutableTreeNode`s and not `TreeNode`s, might not be an issue, but you might want to keep it in mind.

The `haveCompleteNode` seems to be stopping you from moving a branch node if its child elements aren't selected ... which seems somewhat weird to me.

Also, the code following it seems to prevent you from moving/copying a node to a position above the source nodes current level ... for some reason

I'm also not sure I'd keep two copies of the selected nodes, this is me, but a defensive copy seems a little over the top (could be a particular edge case, but I'd be worried if the tree can be updated during a drag operation, but that's me).

So, what are the lessons here?

Any code you find on the web is going to need you to spend some time actually figuring out what it's doing.  It might start out as a good fit for your needs, but at some point in time, you're going to have to pull up your sleeves and dig into to modify it for your own needs.

The first thing you should do is get a good understanding of the [Drag and Drop and Data Transfer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html) APIs.

The following is a modified example of the code you linked, which will allow you to move a branch node (and its children) and also allow you to move them to a position "above" their source depth.

But again - you need to take the time to understand what the code is doing and be prepared to modify it to your needs

```
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.DropMode;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.TransferHandler;
import static javax.swing.TransferHandler.COPY_OR_MOVE;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeSelectionModel;

public class TreeDragAndDrop {

    private JScrollPane getContent() {
        JTree tree = new JTree();
        tree.setDragEnabled(true);
        tree.setDropMode(DropMode.ON_OR_INSERT);
        tree.setTransferHandler(new TreeTransferHandler());
        tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(
                TreeSelectionModel.CONTIGUOUS_TREE_SELECTION);
        expandTree(tree);
        return new JScrollPane(tree);
    }

    private void expandTree(JTree tree) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root
                = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) tree.getModel().getRoot();
        Enumeration e = root.breadthFirstEnumeration();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node
                    = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e.nextElement();
            if (node.isLeaf()) {
                continue;
            }
            int row = tree.getRowForPath(new TreePath(node.getPath()));
            tree.expandRow(row);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new TreeDragAndDrop().getContent());
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setLocation(200, 200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    class TreeTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {

        DataFlavor nodesFlavor;
        DataFlavor[] flavors = new DataFlavor[1];

        public TreeTransferHandler() {
            try {
                String mimeType = DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType
                        + ";class=\""
                        + javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode[].class.getName()
                        + "\"";
                nodesFlavor = new DataFlavor(mimeType);
                flavors[0] = nodesFlavor;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("ClassNotFound: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
            if (!support.isDrop()) {
                return false;
            }
            support.setShowDropLocation(true);
            if (!support.isDataFlavorSupported(nodesFlavor)) {
                System.out.println("Unsupported flavor");
                return false;
            }
            // Do not allow a drop on the drag source selections.
            JTree.DropLocation dl
                    = (JTree.DropLocation) support.getDropLocation();
            JTree tree = (JTree) support.getComponent();
            int dropRow = tree.getRowForPath(dl.getPath());
            int[] selRows = tree.getSelectionRows();
            for (int i = 0; i < selRows.length; i++) {
                if (selRows[i] == dropRow) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            // This seems to stop the node from been copied to a level above itself?!
//            TreePath dest = dl.getPath();
//            DefaultMutableTreeNode target = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) dest.getLastPathComponent();
//            TreePath path = tree.getPathForRow(selRows[0]);
//            DefaultMutableTreeNode firstNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();
//            if (firstNode.getChildCount() > 0 && target.getLevel() < firstNode.getLevel()) {
//                return false;
//            }
            return true;
        }

        protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {
            JTree tree = (JTree) c;
            TreePath[] paths = tree.getSelectionPaths();
            if (paths != null) {
                // Make up a node array of copies for transfer and
                // another for/of the nodes that will be removed in
                // exportDone after a successful drop.
                List<DefaultMutableTreeNode> copies = new ArrayList<DefaultMutableTreeNode>();

                for (int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode next = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) paths[i].getLastPathComponent();
                    System.out.println("Selected = " + next.getUserObject());
                    copies.add(next);
                }
                DefaultMutableTreeNode[] nodes = copies.toArray(new DefaultMutableTreeNode[copies.size()]);
                return new NodesTransferable(nodes);
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Defensive copy used in createTransferable.
         */
        private DefaultMutableTreeNode copy(TreeNode node) {
            return new DefaultMutableTreeNode(node);
        }

        protected void exportDone(JComponent source, Transferable data, int action) {
            // Already dealt with this
        }

        public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
            return COPY_OR_MOVE;
        }

        public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
            System.out.println("Import here");
            if (!canImport(support)) {
                return false;
            }
            // Extract transfer data.
            DefaultMutableTreeNode[] nodes = null;
            try {
                Transferable t = support.getTransferable();
                nodes = (DefaultMutableTreeNode[]) t.getTransferData(nodesFlavor);
            } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ufe) {
                System.out.println("UnsupportedFlavor: " + ufe.getMessage());
            } catch (java.io.IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println("I/O error: " + ioe.getMessage());
            }
            // Get drop location info.
            JTree.DropLocation dl = (JTree.DropLocation) support.getDropLocation();
            int childIndex = dl.getChildIndex();
            TreePath dest = dl.getPath();
            DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) dest.getLastPathComponent();
            JTree tree = (JTree) support.getComponent();
            DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
            // Configure for drop mode.
            int index = childIndex;    // DropMode.INSERT
            if (childIndex == -1) {     // DropMode.ON
                index = parent.getChildCount();
            }

            // One consideration to consider is what to do if it's a different
            // source model ... and it's only a "copy" operation
            // Might want to look into that
            for (DefaultMutableTreeNode node : nodes) {
                model.removeNodeFromParent(node);
            }

            // Add data to model.
            for (DefaultMutableTreeNode node : nodes) {
                model.insertNodeInto(node, parent, index++);
            }
            return true;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return getClass().getName();
        }

        public class NodesTransferable implements Transferable {

            DefaultMutableTreeNode[] nodes;

            public NodesTransferable(DefaultMutableTreeNode[] nodes) {
                this.nodes = nodes;
            }

            public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor)
                    throws UnsupportedFlavorException {
                if (!isDataFlavorSupported(flavor)) {
                    throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
                }
                return nodes;
            }

            public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
                return flavors;
            }

            public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
                return nodesFlavor.equals(flavor);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As far as "code I found on the web", this isn't too bad.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I didn't think of simply deleting the code that was validating my data away! I adjusted my class to pretty much mirror your improvements and I already had my custom data model implemented. Everything inside the `TransferHandler` now works like a charm! I'm currently still getting a `RunTimeException` caused by a `ConcurrentModificationException`, but that seems to be due to my handling of updating the model according to the TreeNodes. Move over 13 year old CR-Thread, this should now be the must-link answer concerning d&d with Swing components!